# Angular directive on generated HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on an existing website that currently use jQuery and PHP.
On a page, HTML code is generated by jQuery AJAX calling PHP code.
How would one add angular directives to this HTML code ?

For example, the PHP code generates :

```
<div class="testDiv">click me</div>
```

I would like :

```
<div class="testDiv" ng-click="angularFunction()">click me</div>
```

As I understand it, angular directives need to be compiled using $compile.
Is there a function like jQuery's "on" function I can use ?

Thanks

Comment: You dont need to use $compile, just google angular directives to learn the basics

Comment: My issue is that since the HTML code is generated by Ajax call, simply adding angular directive to the markup doesn't work.

Comment: you can use ng-include to get the code. DOM to add angular is not adviced

Comment: If the code is not manipulated by the server side, yes use ng-include

Answer (score 0):

In that case, yes use $compile. If you want to learn angular forget the way you do things in jquery. If you try to mimic jquery that most likely will be wrong. That's why they call it the angular way.